# Help with aligning expressions while ignoring negative signs

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularray

How can I align these expressions to the left while ignoring the negative signs (from F1 to F3)? I was considering using the 'dcolumn' package, but it is only designed to work with numeric data.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
colspec={clll},
hlines}

\textbf{Name} & \textbf{F1} & \textbf{F2} &\textbf{F3}\\

A & $-\frac{1}{x}$ & $\frac{1}{x}$ & $-1\leq x\leq 0$ \\
C & $\frac{y}{1+y}$ & $-\frac{1}{1+y}$ & $0\leq y\leq \frac{1}{2}$\\


\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved the problem by using `\phantom{-}`.

[image]

```
\begin{tblr}{
colspec={clll},
hlines}

\textbf{Name} & \SetCell[c=1]{c}{\textbf{F1}} & \SetCell[c=1]{c}{\textbf{F2}} &\SetCell[c=1]{c}{\textbf{F3}}\\

A & $-\frac{1}{x}$ & $\phantom{-}\frac{1}{x}$ & $-1\leq x\leq 0$ \\
C & $\phantom{-}\frac{y}{1+y}$ & $-\frac{1}{1+y}$ & $\phantom{-}0\leq y\leq \frac{1}{2}$\\


\end{tblr}
```